# Command-line repository

Tags: feature-request

It would be useful to have a collective page where people can record their CLI one liners that have been popping up all over *nix SE. Similar to commandlinefu.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think so. Or rather, I think that's useful for sites like the one you mention ([commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/)), but I don't think Stack Exchange is the right engine for a collective page of one-liners. How would you find one that solves a *particular* problem?

If one-liners are the real solution to a particular Unix/Linux problem, they're welcome in the particular question they belong to.

Comment: +1 there's also a quality problem. i've come across some *really bad* commandlinefu... just a property of that general process (it's inherently quantitative to compile/anthologize under a single subject heading, isn't it?) in my opinion; the idea is quality, not quantity.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it would be identical to commandlinefu, and commandlinefu is already set up to do it. Stack Exchange isn't good at big compendiums of information on a subject -- it's designed for finding a specific answer to a specific question. A question like "what cool one-liners do you know?" is too broad, doesn't have a single answer, isn't [solving a particular problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), and is better off left on sites like commandlinefu that are designed for that sort of thing

Answer (score 1):

Pressing commands into one line makes them harder to read, and therefore not so useful in support.

I often develop my solution as one liner, but break it up for publishing.